# Qual o objetivo de usar o "&" na passagem de parâmetros para funções em PHP?

Tags: php, funções

Boas pessoal,

Seguindo a lógica dos ponteiros deparei-me com o seguinte problema.
Se executar a função debaixo usando o "&" o consumo de memória do PHP sobe, não deveria ser o contrário visto que estou a passar a mesma variável em vez de passar uma referência?

```
$teste = 'teste';

function test($teste) {} // consome menos memória
```

ou

```
function test(&$teste) {} // consome mais memória
```

O meu teste foi executado na versão 7.1 do PHP.

Obrigado

Comment: @Maniero , não creio que essa resposta aborde esta questão em termos de performance/consumo , acho esta questão pertinente e não creio que em php tenhamos alguma que explique porque "consumo de memória do PHP sobe, não deveria ser o contrário visto que estou a passar a mesma variável em vez de passar uma referência?"

Comment: @Miguel é verdade mesmo, mas aí não sei se tem uma explicação lógica e factual para isto, inclusive nem sabemos como o teste foi feito. Só com o código postado não tem como ver se mudou o consumo de memória de forma confiável. Então ou não estaria clara ou nem pode ser reproduzido.

Comment: @Maniero pelo que sabemos o AP testou, "...o consumo de memória do PHP sobe" . Confesso que estou curioso mas não tenho tempo agora para dispender com pesquisas/testes. Mas de facto deve ser difícil arranjar uma explicação focada em php para isso